# Z3 Sudoku Solver

Tags: z3, sudoku, smt

I was on the site rise4fun a few weeks ago and they had a python code that converted a sudoku puzzle input file to z3. I checked again today and the file is gone, and was wondering if anyone had this code or could explain to me how to implement it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 9):

```
    # 9x9 matrix of integer variables
X = [ [ Int("x_%s_%s" % (i+1, j+1)) for j in range(9) ] 
      for i in range(9) ]

# each cell contains a value in {1, ..., 9}
cells_c  = [ And(1 <= X[i][j], X[i][j] <= 9) 
             for i in range(9) for j in range(9) ]

# each row contains a digit at most once
rows_c   = [ Distinct(X[i]) for i in range(9) ]

# each column contains a digit at most once
cols_c   = [ Distinct([ X[i][j] for i in range(9) ]) 
             for j in range(9) ]

# each 3x3 square contains a digit at most once
sq_c     = [ Distinct([ X[3*i0 + i][3*j0 + j] 
                        for i in range(3) for j in range(3) ]) 
             for i0 in range(3) for j0 in range(3) ]

sudoku_c = cells_c + rows_c + cols_c + sq_c

# sudoku instance, we use '0' for empty cells
instance = ((5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0),
            (6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0),
            (0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0),
            (8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3),
            (4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1),
            (7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6),
            (0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0),
            (0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5),
            (0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9))

instance_c = [ If(instance[i][j] == 0, 
                  True, 
                  X[i][j] == instance[i][j]) 
               for i in range(9) for j in range(9) ]

s = Solver()
s.add(sudoku_c + instance_c)
if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    r = [ [ m.evaluate(X[i][j]) for j in range(9) ] 
          for i in range(9) ]
    print_matrix(r)
else:
    print "failed to solve"
```